# is_feed() not working for Custom Post Types

Tags: wordpress, rss, custom-post-type

I have a CPT called quotes with ACFs that I want to add to my RSS feed.

My rss url is `example.com/feed/?post_type=quotes`

When I use `is_feed()` this code works. But it doesn't work when I try to limit it to only the quotes CPT using: `is_feed('quotes')`

```
function add_fields_to_rss ($content) {  
    if(is_feed('quotes')) {
        $post_id = get_the_ID();
        $output = '<div><p>' . get_field('the_quote', $post_id) . '</p>';
        $output .= '<h3 style="text-align: right;">' . get_field('quoted', $post_id) . '</h3>';
        $output .= '</div>';
        $content = $content.$output;
    }
    return $content;
}
add_filter('the_content','add_fields_to_rss');
```

Is there anything else I need to do so that this function will work with my quotes CPT only?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CPT creates default rss links in the form of `My rss url is example.com/feed/?post_type=my_post_type`

If seems that doesn't work with `is_feed('my_post_type')`

I'm guessing to make it work you need to create the feed with `add_feed()`

But I didn't test that because I went another way.

Answer (score 0):

if I understand currently you want to add all custom posts types to the rss feed?
If so the following should work:

```
add_filter( 'request', 'myfeed_request' );
function myfeed_request( $qv ) {
if ( isset( $qv['feed'] ) ) {
// gett all custom posts types 
$qv['post_type'] = get_post_types();
}
return $qv;
}
```

Tell me if this is what you're looking for

**EDIT 1**: Aswering your updated question and comment

The following is for adding specific customs posts types to the rss feed

```
<?php add_filter( 'request', 'multiple_CPT_to_rss' );
function multiple_CPT_to_rss( $qv ) {
if ( isset( $qv['feed'] ) && !isset( $qv['post_type'] ) ) {
$qv['post_type'] = array( 'post', 'my_CPT_1', 'my_CPT_2' );
}
return $qv;
}; ?>
```

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I only want this snippet to apply to the CPT: quotes
But when I put in is_feed('quotes') it stops working. Thanks.

Comment: Edited my last post, tell me if this is what you're looking for

Comment: I don't want to add multiple CPTs to the RSS feed. Each CPT has its own feed, eg. example.com/feed/?post_type=quotes. I just want my function to only modify the feed for quotes. Sorry if I haven't been precise.